# ESLint only target a specific directory (eslintrc, create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I have a folder structure similar to this:

```
/root
 .eslintrc.json
 package.json
 /someFolder
   /sub
   /sub
 /anotherFolder
 /src
   /containers
   /components
 /oneMoreFolder
   /sub
   /sub
```

I'm working with create-react-app and am applying airbnb rules. I have been able to run the linter in a specific folder easily from the CLI but on compile, it targets ALL folders.

I want to run the linter on compile on just the files within the **/src** folder.

How can I go about this? I've tried a number of solutions.

Thank you!

*TL:DR How do I target just one subfolder and all of its files on compile when using eslint and create-react-app?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to do something like `eslint src/**/*.js[x]`. If you are running a webpack build(or precommit hook) that does linting check then add it within the `scripts` object inside `package.json`.

Comment: When I ran this command, I got an error that no paths matched that format. I had luck with this instead: `eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}`

Comment: How can I limit this via the .eslintrc.json file?

Comment: @Vahid I recommend using `.eslintignore` instead, if you want to ignore certain files. Another way is while you run the `eslint` command make the path to files more tighter. `eslintrc` file should be used for setting up the config.

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/.eslintignore

Answer (score 34):

inside your `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [ 2, "double" ]
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "src/**/*.js" ],
      "rules": {
        "quotes": [ 2, "single" ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

in `.eslintignore`

```
 /someFolder
 /anotherFolder
 /oneMoreFolder
```

Comment: As others have mentioned, you can use `"ignorePatterns": ["/someFolder", ...]` inside of your eslintrc file. This allows you to keep it all in one place.

Answer (score 22):

I used `ignorePatterns` option. It'll tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories. It's useful when your IDE (ex. VS Code) is reporting errors in unwanted files.

```
{
  "ignorePatterns": ["gulpfile.js", "gulp/**/*", "webpack.config.js"]
}
```

You can Also use the `.eslintignore` file.

Answer (score 5):

Where you have written the script to run lint in `package.json`, there only mention the folders you want to target

```
scripts:{"lint": "eslint src public"}
```

Then if you want to ignore some type of files in the respective folders, you can mention in ESLint config file.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use bracket notation to specify a list of directories that you'd like an override to be applied for

```json
overrides: [
  {
    files: ["packages/{dev-scripts,migrations,bootstrap}/**/*.{ts,js}"],
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    rules: {
      "no-console": "off",
    },
  },
];
```